# is an array of uniform sampler2d possible?

Tags: opengl-es

I'm trying to get rid of branching logic in my frag shader, so I'm attempting to say `uniform sampler2d texunit[6];` and then access it with `frag=texture(texunit[id],vtex);` where `id` is a `flat int` from the vertex shader. It runs without error but draws nothing.

Google wasn't much help except someone said you can if the indices are known at runtime but I don't know what they mean.

edit: to be more thorough here is the relevant client side code: 
          glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shaderid,"texture_unit[0]",0),0);
        and etc, just replacing the 0 with the relevant id.

edit: i got this working just as it should. i dont know what was wrong before. but it works, as does sampler2DArray[id]

edit: ive determined why it wasnt working at first: when you choose which index into the sampler2d or sampler2darray to use, to choose which tex unit, well, thats the only index that can be used in the frag shader. you can use a variable, thankfully, but then you cant in another place use a literal, or it will break.

Comment: Are you using desktop OpenGL or OpenGL ES?

Comment: opengl es 3 for android

Comment: ES 3.0, 3.1, or 3.2?

Comment: just 3.0 but i guess i could switch to .1 or .2 if need be